# Calculating the wavelength of incident photon in Compton scattering event

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, photons, electrons, wavelength

'In the Compton scattering event, the scattered photon has an energy of $120$ keV and the recoiling electron has an energy of $40$ keV. Find the wavelength of the incident photon.'

I thought, to solve this problem, that the expression for conservation of energy gives

$$E+mc^2=E'+E(e),$$

where $E$ is the energy of the incident photon, $E'$ is the energy of the scattered photo, $mc^2$ is the rest energy of the electron, and $E(e)$ is the total relativistic energy of the electron after the collision.
So,

$$E=E'+E(e)-mc^2,$$

$$hc/λ=E'+E(e)-mc^2,$$

$$λ=hc/(E'+E(e)-mc^2),$$

but the solution of this problem says it's

$$ λ=hc/(E'+E(e)).$$

Why isn't the rest energy of electron considered??

Thank you for reading this!